# Why was the saucer separation so rarely done on the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, uss-enterprise

There are many occasions where saucer separation on the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-D) would have come in handy but it was only done a few times.

Is there a reason they did not do it more often? It seemed to take only a few minutes to disconnect and a few minutes more to reconnect.

I am guessing that it was hard on the ship and would require follow up maintenance.

Comment: Because Picard hated it.

Comment: @Richard I don't think so, he did it the very first chance he got. I am wondering if Geordie(No not Geordi, Sarah MacDougal?) yelled at him after.

Comment: because it was a stupid idea

Comment: For exactly the same reason I haven't used 99.9% of the features on my phone since the day I bought it.

Comment: I wish I had my old STTNG tech manual, I think it talks about wear and tear.

Comment: I would find the reverse question more interesting: how often is this actually advantageous? You mention "many occasions." Please name some and explain how it would have helped the situation. I think the question is a little vague without that info.

Comment: @jpmc26 You make a strong point. At first I was thinking any situation too dangerous to bring the non-essential crew into, but really lifepods could evacuate those people in a pinch. The battle of Wolf 359 first came to mind, they could have left most of the crew behind on what seemed at the time to be a suicide mission. I agree you have a good question there, if you don't ask it I will.

Comment: So wait, if I'm reading these wikis correctly, this separation essentially dumps all the non-combatants in a giant, unwieldy section of the ship that has no warp capability and presumably limited offensive or defensive capabilities, and then they're told to bugger off back to base? **And this is considered tactically *advantageous*?**

Comment: @Lilienthal - I think the idea is that you park the families in orbit of a friendly planet (or deep space out of everyone's way) while the weapons platform goes off to confront the baddies.

Comment: @Himarm That didn't stop them from taking it a step further with the Prometheus!

Comment: @Michael: That was entirely different, though! The Prometheus's segments were all heavily armed and warp-capable.... and _not_ designed to carry non-combatants.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### In-Universe explanations

The [TNG Technical Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671704273) (considered a canon source of information about the trek universe) offers several reasons why separations were rare:

### The sequence is intended to be used in "emergencies" only

> The USS Enterprise consists of two spacecraft systems integrated to
> form a single functional vessel. **Under specific emergency conditions,
> the two vehicle elements may perform a separation maneuver and
> continue independent operation.** The two elements, the Saucer Module
> and the Battle Section, are normally joined together by a series of
> structural docking latches, numerous umbilicals, and turbolift
> pass-throughs.

### Separations actually damage the ship

> T**he latching system has been designed to accept a failure rate of 1.5
> latch pairs per ten separations;** in the event a single pair fails to
> seat properly within its passive aperture, the structural loads can be
> shared adequately among the other latches.
>
> ...
>
> **Should any key umbilicals or turbo paths show a failure condition at
> the vehicle interface, the computer will close off the affected
> elements at the best possible points upstream of the failure. Hardware
> and software failures will then be dealt with later, once the
> emergency situation is resolved.** Crews on both sides of the vehicle
> interface monitor the progress of the separation sequence, and are
> then on standby awaiting reconnection duties.

We also see some reasoning within the show itself:

### Separating the ship actually *harms* the ship's ability to maneuver in close combat.

> **SHELBY:** *There's one other recommendation I'd like to make, Commander. Separate the saucer section... assign a skeleton crew to create a diversion...*
>
> **RIKER:** (shakes his head) ***We may need power from the saucer impulse engines...*** -  <sup><sub>[TNG: Best of Both Worlds, Pt I](http://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/174.txt)</sub></sup>

### Separating represents a potentially 'mission-ending' hazard

And finally, we see in [TNG: Encounter at Farpoint](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/102.txt), Pt I the difficulty of rejoining the ship manually. It stands to reason that a computer failure at a critical time (and let's face it, those happen every other episode) could severely damage both halves of the ship, immediately ending their mission and resulting in an embarrassing trip to the nearest Stardock so that the repair crew can <s>laugh at you</s> fix the ship

---

### Out of Universe Explanations

There were several out-of-universe reasons, largely relating to the relative expense of filming sequences, lack of models and the extra storytelling time needed to see the sequence itself and the extra scripting required to explain the rules of how separation occurs:

### They only had one (obsolete) model that could actually separate, severely limiting their ability to shoot

> Though less favored by Rob Legato and Dan Curry and largely unused
> since the appearance of its four-foot cousin in season three, **the
> original six-foot Enterprise model had to be hauled out of storage for
> the ship-separation sequence in the Borg battle, since it was the only
> version built in two sections.** The various battle effects and Borg
> visuals are motion-picture quality, but again TNG struck out with the
> Emmys for special effects. Part 2 was nominated, but it won no awards
> in that category. The episode did snag Emmys for sound editing and for
> sound mixing, as well as a nomination for art direction. - <sub><sup>**[TNG Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743457986)**</sup></sub>

### It slowed down the plot

Apparently there were a number of attempts by writers to add a ship-separation sequence, all shot down by the producers.

> This was an opportunity to utilize those often ignored shipboard
> families that Shearer initially pitched to Fontana, and it was this
> story that helped win her a spot on the writing staff. **A subplot [in TNG: When the Bough Breaks]
> involving ship separation and the saucer being held hostage was phased
> out to focus on the main story.** <sub><sup>**[TNG Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743457986)**</sup></sub>

Ironically, this tendency for the separation sequence to eat up time was actually *helpful* in the pilot episode in extending it to feature-length

> According to Justman, **both the ship separation sequence and a touching
> scene in which an aged Admiral McCoy meets Data were a help in filling
> out what Fontana had intended to be a ninety-minute script.** <sub><sup>**[TNG Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743457986)**</sup></sub>

### Because of the time and expense involved

Notably, the [Battle Bridge set](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/reused_ship_interiors.htm) was quite expensive to build and the studio preferred not to create sets when they could avoid it.

> During the first few episodes of Star Trek: The Next Generation,
> **saucer separation was intended to be a standard maneuver in combat
> situations, but was rarely done because of the costs for visual
> effects and for rebuilding the Battle Bridge; also, it was felt that
> it slowed down story-telling too much.** - <sub><sup>[**TNG Encyclopedia**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671536095)</sup></sub>

Comment: Blast! Beat me to it!

Comment: Useful (as always), but I think the wording of the question suggests a preference for an in universe answer. (Notes about occasions where it would be "handy" and wear and tear on the ship itself are in universe considerations.)

Comment: I was hoping for an in universe answer but I still gave this answer a +1 for being full of interesting info.

Comment: @HighInBC - I've added some in-universe reasoning now I've got access to my books and I've shifted the "out-of-universe" stuff to the bottom. Let me know if there's anything else you think needs addressing

Comment: @jpmc26 - I've found some in-universe reasons too

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItUECpFi9_s

Comment: As an aside, I remember thinking when I saw the pilot, "WTF? That's the dumbest thing ever..." And proceeding to boycot the show.  I popped in on it from time to time but generally that scene cost them my viewership

Comment: @Paul - I put it down to "pilot episode wackiness". Sometimes abilities/plots are written into a pilot that don't make it into the main show. Riker's ability to communicate telepathically with Troi also disappeared.

Comment: @Valorum Nowadays I probably would too.  I was a bit more harsh in my judgements in my youth.

Answer (score 14):

In-universe, on many occasions the Enterprise came upon dangerous situations by surprise, so even a few minutes may be too long.

Additionally, the saucer is more vulnerable when separate, as it lacks warp capability (so if separated in a danger zone, it cannot escape danger except by hoping that nobody takes a pot-shot at it while it limps away) and loses access to the main engineering power stores (though obviously it has other sources of power) so its weapon and shield capability would most likely be decreased.

When the Enterprise crew knows ahead of time that they're heading into danger, it's a little harder to make the case, but there are still some justifications:

- Reduced medical rooms and staff due to being split between the two.
- The standard shape for most Federation ships is due to this being the "most efficient" for the warp bubble; presumably having the saucer gone will make the warp drive less efficient, reducing either speed or final power reserves.  Both speed and power can be critical to mission success.
- Cramped quarters for battle crew due to most of the living quarters being in the saucer.  This doesn't matter too much for short fights but could be problematic for longer missions or even just if travel time between the "safe zone" where the saucer is left and the mission target is more than a day or so.  It'd be quite problematic if your crew is no longer battle-ready by the time you get there.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that the stardrive section was more efficient in terms of speed and longevity.

Comment: I think the saucer being vulnerable on its own is a *very* good in-universe explanation. Splitting up would result in *two* targets for an enemy to attack; one effectively defenseless and dead-in-space, the other tactically tied to the former. Overall, not a good situation to be in. I am sure that Starfleet designers would have thought of that *before* actually building the Enterprise that way... as opposed to, say, directors on the lookout for eye candy. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar They eventually figured out the right way to do it, what with the _Prometheus_ having THREE warp- and battle-capable sections. And being controllable by the EMH in a pinch.

Comment: @DevSolar - According to the TNG manual, the saucer was optimised for defensive operations. Basically they could run a higher strength shield.

Comment: @Richard: Which still nails the "battle part" with one foot to the floor.

Comment: @DevSolar How is having two, independently maneuverable targets worse than one? Generally, outnumbering your opponent is a *good* thing. They could use the battle section to hammer the enemy, then when shields get low, switch so that the saucer section's shields take the hits while laying down enough phaser fire to keep the enemy's shields from recharging. Once the battle section's shields are back up and the torpedoes reloaded, switch back. Even if you didn't do it like that, it seems like having the enemy split its fire amongst 2 targets is a tactical advantage.

Comment: Because it's also a sitting duck, with no warp capability - you can threaten it and force an unfavourable engagement. Or leave it and move the fight away from it. Two ships of equal capability would be tactically advantageous. Splitting your firepower, and leaving some of it behind on something that can't keep up with the fight considerably less so.

Comment: @Shane: What Sobrique said. And that saucer section holds the *families* of the tactical staff in the battle section. You want that saucer *safe*, not part of the battle, and not something the enemy can take hostage, so the battle section will have to *consider* the saucer section, continuously. No quick retreat when the battle goes sour, either.

Comment: @DevSolar not exactly defenseless; see [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109885/22917)

Comment: @Sobrique Engagements aren't fought at warp, so how does them not having warp allow you to threaten them? It still has impulse, shields, and weapons. And you really can't warp off and somehow move the fight away from the saucer. If you warp away, *you've warped away*. Except for warp -which isn't a tactical consideration - both sections are fairly close to equally capable. Not *identically* capable, but still.

Comment: @DevSolar Wanting the saucer safe and not in battle isn't a very good reason to not separate in battle. I can't see how you could take them hostage. At least, not how they are more susceptible to being taken hostage. Not being able to perform a quick retreat is a good point, that would have to be a big consideration.

Comment: Warp a short way - either they pursue and lose half their firepower,  or they don't and might as well not have warp.  And then you can trivially hit and fade, launching a volley of torpedoes at the slow moving turkey and warp before they can return significant fire.

Comment: @Shane: I suppose you could ostensibly leave the saucer behind then perform the Picard Maneuver with the stardrive section to surprise the vultures :)

Comment: IIRC the saucer has warp coils, but no warp core, so it can sustain a warp field (similar to photon torpedoes). The downside is that the separation has to occur during warp.